# How to create a task for Salesforce cloud crm using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, salesforcedx, ssjs

Please advise how to create a task for Salesforce object in MC using ampscript.please let me know is this functionality is achievable

Regards
Shiva

Comment: Please take time to do a little research before posting your question. What you are asking is really basic and achievable. Checkout this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm

Comment: Please put more effort in your questions. So far the questions you've asked are either been closed or put on hold. Keeping on asking in this poor way, will not help you here on SFSE.

Comment: Thanks for advice,i will try to put effort before posting,as I'm in learning stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) to create a task. Also you probably will need to lookup the user to create this task for, and will hence need [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) to get the ID

Comment: Thanks for gudliene guys

Comment: @shivadn Remember to accept/upvote